# javascript alert doesnt pop up on php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to show a popup alert when user uploaded a file
I have 1 php file that contains php script and html form, when I click the submit button the file was saved. But the echo function that contains javascript alert doesnt pop up. Can anyone help me?

here's my code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{
    if($_FILES["photo"]["name"])
    {
        $name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
        $size = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
        $type = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
        if(!$_FILES["photo"]["error"])
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/coba2.jpg");
            $msg = "Upload Berhasil\nFile Name: $name\nSize: $size bytes\nType: $type";
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Upload ERROR: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "No File Uploaded";
    }
    if(isset($msg))
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(".$msg.");</script>";
    }       
}?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coba Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Select File to Upload</h3><br>
    <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="photo" size="50"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Unggah Foto">  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering why the echo that contains javascript alert doesnt pop up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to put inside the `<head>` tag

Comment: Do the script tags get appended? Are they visible in the HTML?

Comment: does the line `if(isset($msg))` get executed

Comment: Does your code reach that point? Can you provide some kind of log statement or PHP echo to say you've gotten there, and it's definitely the JS that isn't working?

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code that gets rendered here?  If your JavaScript isn't working, the first step is to actually look at your JavaScript.

Comment: javascript takes the `$msg` variable as a js variable. You need to add quotes around `$msg`

Comment: also your action attribute on your html form seems funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `msg` needs to be contained within quotes to `alert` correctly, so change:

```
{
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(".$msg.");</script>";
}
```

To:

```
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
}
```

Or, to continue using escaped quotes (urgh!):

```
{
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"".$msg."\");</script>"
}
```

Comment: thanks it's working now if no files uploaded, but when I try to upload a file (it is saved in my directory) the $msg does not pop up.

Comment: @aldo-adhi, The context of the question has now changed. Can I suggest that you mark this question as complete and create a new question for help with the message contents. This will avoid confusion when people come to see the answer to your initial question.